# Reference book for problem solving (Multivariable Calculus).

Tags: multivariable-calculus

I am preparing for an entrance exam so I'm looking for a book that discusses and covers mainly **techniques and methods** to solve different kinds and types of problems on limits of multiple variables, multiple integrals etc.

Most of the books that were recommended to me in my undergraduate classes were theory books which were centered around proofs and well... theory.

Please note that I am **NOT** looking for a theory book (like Tom Apostol) which doesn't cover problem solving *intensively*. I am familiar with theory (at least most of it, I hope). I know how to go about doing proofs and everything but I'm extremely terrible at problem solving and hence this question. Any help is appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Can you be more specific on the topics you wish to cover?

Comment: I'd be happy with even Limits/continuity and multiple integrals, I suppose but if it covers more topics, even better! Also it doesn't have to be all in one book. I don't mind if you'd recommend different books for different topics.

Answer (score 1):

A few books comes to mind: (1) [Multivariable Mathematics](https://www.wiley.com/en-us/Multivariable+Mathematics%3A+Linear+Algebra%2C+Multivariable+Calculus%2C+and+Manifolds-p-9780471526384), by Theodore Shifrin has lot's of enlightening examples and exercise on multivariable limits. (2) [Basic Multivariable Calculus](https://www.springer.com/gp/book/9780387979762), by Jerrold E. Marsden has quite a few exercises and examples on limits, integrals.

Some books that i can think right now; dedicated to problem solving is: (1) [Solving Problems in Mathematical Analysis, Part II](https://www.springer.com/gp/book/9783030368470), by Tomasz Radożycki. Part II will specifically serve your interests. (2) [Problems in Mathematical Analysis II: Continuity and Differentiation](https://bookstore.ams.org/stml-12), by Kaczor & Nowak can be a handy reference too. Both (1) and (2) contains full solution to the problems.

Answer (score 0):

I think you may try once the following book

"Schaum's Outline of Advanced Calculus" by  Robert Wrede & Murray Spiegel

The book contains a large number of exercises with solutions. The essence of the theory is briefly repeated and then it goes to practice. Ideal for exam preparation - English is simple and easy to understand.